# iPhone required device capabilities - memory

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to set a minimum memory requirement, so the App cannot be installed on devices that do not have enough memory to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You have to use other device requirements in your plist as a surrogate; and this method could get obsoleted by future device releases.  Note that the memory available to an app at launch will vary significantly by iOS version and by what the user has left running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: info.plist

Long answer: Please refer to the following links:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4457

http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/archives/2010/february/#setdevicesinplist

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Memory is not listed in required device capabilities documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html), and since the required device capabilities are boolean (you have a camera or not, for example), while memory requirement is a value, I was hopping there were some other way to set the required memory.